# jquery-ui draggable: change clone helper's css margin correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a problem with setting css margin property of the cloned helper div element.

There are three frames in the following example: green frame is the dragged items storage, blue frame is for dropping, red frame limits the place for dragging. I would like to place items in the middle of the green frame but enable the dragged item to move in the red frame close to all borders.

So all items in the green frame have css margin: 8px auto, for the cloned helper I try to change margin to 0 with ui.helper.css('margin', '0'). The problem is that the dragged item does not want to move to the lower right corner of the red frame.

You can find [jsfiddle project here](http://jsfiddle.net/0or2uauo/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main-container">
<div id="stock">
<div class="block">drag me to the right bottom corner of the red border</div>
</div>
<div id="workspace">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-container {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
bottom: 20px;
right: 20px;
border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

#stock {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
bottom: 5px;
width: 180px;
border: 2px solid #00ff00;
}

#workspace {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 185px;
bottom: 5px;
right: 5px;
border: 2px solid #0000ff;
}

.block {
height: 100px;
width: 150px;
border: 1px solid #2e6f9a;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #e0e0e0;
border-radius: 8px;
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in;

margin: 8px auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.block').draggable({
appendTo: '#main-container',
containment: $('#main-container'),
helper: 'clone',
cursor: 'move',
revertDuration: 100,
revert: 'invalid',
start: function(ev, ui) {
    ui.helper.css('margin', '0');
    ui.helper.css('background-color', 'red');
}
});

$('#workspace').droppable({
accept: '.block',
tolerance: 'fit'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the jquery-ui itself. `ui.helper.css('margin', '0')` does its work, but this is absolutely not enough, because jquery-ui incorrectly determines the position of the mouse pointer on the cloned helper when it is created.

The solution is not trivial but it works.
First remove `margin: 8px auto;` from the .block css and create new class style

```
.margin_8px_auto {
    margin: 8px auto;
}
```

Second add this style to the element with .block style

```
<div class="block margin_8px_auto">drag me to the right bottom corner of the red border</div>
```

Finally, change the javascript code as follows:

```
$('.block').draggable({
    appendTo: '#main-container',
    containment: $('#main-container'),
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    revertDuration: 100,
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: function(ev, ui) {
        var $elem = $(this);
        var pos = $elem.offset();
        var dX = ev.pageX - pos.left;
        var dY = ev.pageY - pos.top;

        $elem.removeClass('margin_8px_auto');
        $clone = $elem.clone();

        $(this).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
            left: dX,
            top: dY
        });

        return $clone;
    },
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css('background-color', 'red');
        $(this).addClass('margin_8px_auto');
    }
});

$('#workspace').droppable({
    accept: '.block',
    tolerance: 'fit'
});
```

[You can find jsfiddle project here](http://jsfiddle.net/0or2uauo/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Margin: 8px auto is the culprit.
remove that and add

```
position:relative;
right:-10px;
top:10px;
```

Add !important to the margin in start function
i.e

```
ui.helper.css('margin', '0 !important');
```

Comment: I know that removing "margin: 8px auto;" solves the problem with "the red frame". But the question is why $('.block').draggable({ start: function(ev, ui) { ui.helper.css('margin', '0'); }}); doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: add !important to your margin

Comment: $('.block').draggable({ start: function(ev, ui) { ui.helper.css('margin', '0 !important'); }}); doesn't work too. [check it](http://jsfiddle.net/0or2uauo/8/)